# Finding scholarship in England

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom

I am a master's graduate from Iran. I received an admission offer (PhD in business) from one of the reputable universities in England but I don't have scholarship yet. 
My question is: In addition to internal scholarships(I mean the university's) What are external scholarships I can apply for? i.e.  If the university doesn't give me a scholarship, are there other British institutions to fund my phd studies or not? I am exploring all my chances in the remaining time to accept the offer.

Comment: Have you received any advice from the university which made the offer? It seems slightly strange to me that they would make an offer without giving a definite "yes" or "no" to providing a scholarship

Comment: @YemonChoi It doesn't seem odd to me. Some students come with their own funding. Others need confirmation of a place in order to apply for a scholarship. They might be hoping to offer funding to someone, but not yet be in a position to know what money they have or who they will give it to. And right now things in the UK are unusually uncertain.

Comment: @YemonChoi They said No but I am still corresponding to see if there are any chances.

Comment: @JessicaB Fair enough. Speaking only for my own department: it has been comparatively rare that we make an offer without either confirming funding or confirming there is no funding

Comment: @HamidehIraj If they said no, I don't understand why you're asking them if really they meant yes. When they said they didn't have any funding for you, they surely meant that. Or do you mean that you're in corresponding with them about the possibility of external funding?

Comment: @DavidRicherby my question is about external scholarships awarded by institutions outside universities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jobs.ac.uk has a [page about funding a PhD](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/careers-advice/studentships/1534/phd-funding-a-checklist-of-possible-funding-sources/) that includes the following:

> A number of charitable organisations, foundations and trusts can help fund PhD’s. These include:
>
> The Wellcome Trust
>
> Cancer Research UK
>
> The British Academy
>
> The British Federation of Women Graduates
>
> The Institution of Civil Engineers
>
> Institution of Engineering & Technology
>
> Institution of Mechanical Engineers
>
> Royal Geographical Society
>
> Carnegie Trust for the Universities of Scotland
>
> Leverhulme Trust
>
> Action Medical Research

Answer (score -1):

One friend introduced [Islamic Development Bank (IDB) scholarships.](http://www.isdb.org/irj/portal/anonymous?NavigationTarget=navurl://e6a729183f50b834c13c3abf5cc619ae)